# Silverstripe 3: Tinymce, configure external links

Tags: php, tinymce, silverstripe

I want all external links on my SilverStripe site to use https.

In silverstripe, I am using HTMLEditorFields and I would like to configure the options for an external link. By default the link field for an external link will show http://

I want to:

1. Change this to https://
2. Create an onBeforeWrite() function where I can check that the https protocol is present in the link (as the http:// that is originally in the text field can be removed)

Where abouts can I make these changes without changing the original code? I am using SilverStripe 3.

Comment: per JS, may https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/#urlconverter_callback helps you?

Answer (score 1):

An onBeforeWrite() call should resolve your need:

```
public function onBeforeWrite()
{
    parent::onBeforeWrite();

    $this->Content = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $this->Content);
}
```

Please note, this can lead to broken links, if a target website doesn't support https. In 2019 these number should be fairly small and further declining.

Comment: Should this be str_replace

Comment: Yes, you are right. Don't ask me where my mind was at when I typed this. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @spekulatius Am just wondering where I should put this method? How do I use the onBeforeWrite for the external link field specifically as I would also want to add https to any links that may be missing the protocol altogether

Comment: It should go in your apps `Page.php` file - there it would hook and replace http with https. It wouldn't catch any cases of incomplete URL (without protocol) tho. For this you would need to parse the content, identify incomplete urls and fix them.